# Can't use select in Linq statement

Tags: c#, asynchronous, service, controller, task

Sorry if this is a silly question but I am new to LINQ.
I have a service which queries the database using Dapper using the async/await logic. The method in the service I can use SELECT in linq but in the controller this option is not allowing me to? I only have "ToSelectListItems" and not SELECT.. what am I missing here?

Service:

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<AwardWinResult>> GetAwardWinnersAsync(bool useCache = true)
    {
        var data = await awardWinnersRepository.GetWinnersAsync();
        return data;;
    }
```

Controller:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        var awardWinners = await awardWinnersService.GetAwardWinnersAsync();

        var viewModel = new AwardWinnersWrapperVM
        {
            AwardWinners = await awardWinners.SelectMissingHere?(x => new AwardWinnersViewModel
            {
                AwardId = x.AwardId
            })
        };

        return View(awardWinners);
    }
```

Repository:

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<AwardWinResult>> GetWinnersAsync()
    {
        using (var conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(Proj.DataContext.ConnectionString))
        {
            await conn.OpenAsync();

            var data = await conn.QueryAsync<AwardWinResult>(@"
                SELECT aw.[WinnerId], aw.[AwardId], aw.[AwardCategoryId] as CategoryId, a.[Name] as AwardName, ac.[Name] as CategoryName, a.[StartDate], a.[EndDate], a.[LaunchDate]
                FROM [Proj].[AwardWinners] aw
                LEFT JOIN [Proj].[AwardCategories] ac on aw.AwardCategoryId = ac.Id
                LEFT JOIN [Proj].[Awards] a on aw.AwardId = a.Id
                LEFT JOIN [Proj].[AwardJurisdictionGroups] ajg on ac.[JurisdictionGroupId] = ajg.[Id]
                LEFT JOIN [Proj].[AwardWorkareaGroups] awg on ac.[WorkareaGroupId] = awg.[Id]
                ");

            return data.ToList();
        }
    }
```

View model

```
public class AwardWinnersWrapperVM
{
    public IEnumerable<AwardWinnersViewModel> AwardWinners { get; set; }
}

public class AwardWinnersViewModel
{
    public int WinnerId { get; set; }
    public int AwardId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string AwardName { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime LaunchDate { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Did you add a `using System.Linq` statement to the top of your controller file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you don't need `await` in `SelectMissingHere` part:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    var awardWinners = await awardWinnersService.GetAwardWinnersAsync();

    var viewModel = new AwardWinnersWrapperVM
    {
        AwardWinners = awardWinners.Select(x => new AwardWinnersViewModel
        {
            AwardId = x.AwardId
        })
    };

    return View(awardWinners);
}
```

also can you add `AwardWinnersWrapperVM` code, please?

also check for `using System.Linq` directive in your controller.